# run turn server on mac basics

Tags: webrtc, rfc5766turnserver

im using my home macbookpro to deploy a turn server for webrtc app but i cant get it to work and have a few noob questions like :

- i can get mt mac to run coturn but with erros (cant get pass themm
- i have a domain turn.baixocarbono.pt
- i dont know what ips i shoud use on the config
- can i get this to work on my mac?

Please shed some light on whats wrong ! tks

right now i have:

```
realm=turn.baixocarbono.pt
server-name= turn.baixocarbono.pt. //its my domain name
fingerprint
listening-ip=192.168.1.66. // its my computer wifi ip (behind a rooter)
external-ip=85.243.249.150 // its my public rooter ip
listening-port=3478
min-port=10000
max-port=20000
log-file=/turnserver.log
verbose
user=user:pass
lt-cred-mech
```

but i get erros :

```
when i use sudo turnserver -L ip=192.168.1.66 -a -f -r turn.baixocarbono.pt -c /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turnserver.conf --pkey /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_pkey.pem --cert /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_cer.pem i get :


0: TLS supported
0: DTLS supported
0: DTLS 1.2 supported
0: TURN/STUN ALPN supported
0: Third-party authorization (oAuth) is not supported
0: OpenSSL compile-time version: OpenSSL 1.1.1h 22 Sep 2020 (0x1010108f)
0:
0: SQLite supported, default database location is /usr/local/var/db/turndb
0: Redis is not supported
0: PostgreSQL is not supported
0: MySQL is not supported
0: MongoDB is not supported
0:
0: Default Net Engine version: 1 (UDP listening socket per session)

=====================================================

0: Domain name:
0: Default realm: turn.baixocarbono.pt
0: SSL23: Certificate file found: /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_cer.pem
0: SSL23: Private key file found: /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_pkey.pem
0: TLS1.0: Certificate file found: /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_cer.pem
0: TLS1.0: Private key file found: /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_pkey.pem
0: TLS1.1: Certificate file found: /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_cer.pem
0: TLS1.1: Private key file found: /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_pkey.pem
0: TLS1.2: Certificate file found: /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_cer.pem
0: TLS1.2: Private key file found: /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_pkey.pem
0: TLS cipher suite: DEFAULT
0: DTLS: Certificate file found: /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_cer.pem
0: DTLS: Private key file found: /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_pkey.pem
0: DTLS1.2: Certificate file found: /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_cer.pem
0: DTLS1.2: Private key file found: /Users/sam/Downloads/turnserver/turn_server_pkey.pem
0: DTLS cipher suite: DEFAULT
0: Relay address to use: 0.0.0.0
0: pid file created: /var/run/turnserver.pid
0: IO method (main listener thread): kqueue
0: IPv6: On this platform, I am using alternative behavior of TTL (HOPLIMIT) according to RFC 6156.
0: WARNING: I cannot support STUN CHANGE_REQUEST functionality because only one IP address is provided
0: Wait for relay ports initialization...
0: relay 0.0.0.0 initialization...
0: relay 0.0.0.0 initialization done
0: Relay ports initialization done
0: IO method (general relay thread): kqueue
0: turn server id=0 created
0: IO method (general relay thread): kqueue
0: turn server id=1 created
0: IO method (general relay thread): kqueue
0: turn server id=2 created
0: IO method (general relay thread): kqueue
0: turn server id=3 created
0: IO method (general relay thread): kqueue
0: turn server id=4 created
0: IO method (general relay thread): kqueue
0: turn server id=5 created
0: IO method (general relay thread): kqueue
0: turn server id=6 created
0: IO method (general relay thread): kqueue
0: turn server id=7 created
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 0.0.0.0:3478
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 0.0.0.0:5349
socket: Protocol not supported
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 0.0.0.0:3478
socket: Protocol not supported
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 0.0.0.0:5349
0: Total General servers: 8
0: IO method (auth thread): kqueue
0: IO method (auth thread): kqueue
0: IO method (auth thread): kqueue
0: IO method (auth thread): kqueue
0: SQLite DB connection success: /usr/local/var/db/turndb
0: IO method (admin thread): kqueue
0: IPv4. CLI listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5766
43: IPv4. CLI connected to: 127.0.0.1:52939
43: IPv4. CLI connected to: 127.0.0.1:52940
43: IPv4. CLI session disconnected from: 127.0.0.1:52939
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like i need to open the ports